# record video of iOS app on either device or simulator with touch indicator and without cursor

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, video-capture

I want to record a video of my app for my website.  I want it to look professional with a touch indicator to show touches but no cursor and no assistive touch indicator.

I know there are solutions using terminal or quicktime or even screen record on device.  But I haven't found any particular solution that will allow me to show the screen touches but not the cursor.

Ideally the best thing would be to record it on the simulator and have the cursor be represented by a touch indicator which highlights when pressed.

Any professional solution will also be good.  I have access to all adobe applications.

Comment: Premiere pro + EDIT...

Comment: How would you edit premiere pro to do this?  I have tried opening my video in premiere Pro but not sure what you mean.  Do you mean manually create and add the pushes?  That is tedious.  Wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: Tedious? Depends how well you know Pro.. transitions are easy to use and can chop out the cursor but show the moves from screen to screen easily...

Comment: I'm not at all proficient with it but If I can remove the cursor that would be sufficient for me

Comment: youtube it, it's really not that hard. from time to time crossfade.. that's it. You can zoom the timeline in premiere pro, using the 'scroller' on the bottom

Comment: can you actually capture the video in premiere with either iPhone device or simulator?  Or just edit video

Comment: just edit it. Capture it with some other phone or find an app to capture it. If you use your phone, at least you know it's an mp4. Share to your gmail and download on your desktop

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but I did it in a hacky way of subclass `UIApplication` and override the `sendEvent(_:)` function. The function captures the `UITouch` object and give you access to the point of touch. Then in the function you can draw a circle or use a UIImage to indicate the touch point and animate it out after 1 or 2 seconds.

Sample code:

```
class MyApplication: UIApplication {
    override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
        super.sendEvent(event)
        for touch in event.allTouches ?? [] where touch.phase == .ended {
            guard let view = touch.view else { continue }
            let center = touch.location(in: view)
            // You can draw a center using `UIBezierPath` or attach an UIImage to the UIView at this point
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few [apps](https://www.maketecheasier.com/android-screen-recording-apps/) that you can use for capturing your app, including ScreenCam or YouTube Gaming, although the compatibility success may depend on whether your phone is IOS or Android.

If you want to show what your app can be but not show the cursor, you could a) record a video and edit it or b) take screenshots and use transitions to blend one into the other. 
You can use Adobe PremierePro to do either. A cross fade transition can be found under ['Video effects'](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/atv/cs6-tutorials/add-a-transition-between-2-clips.html) . Specify the the length of the transition - for the video , this will be start time (just before the cursor) and the end time (just after).

If you're composing a video from stills, you can extend your stills to last longer by dragging them out to last a few seconds and then add transitions in-between.

If you want to be more specific about your start time, you can ['zoom in'](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2102372&seqNum=4) your timeline , by adjusting the bar at the bottom of the timeline.

Good luck!